# MongoDB gets slower farther into a find() operation

Tags: mongodb, amazon-ec2

I have MongoDB set up on an Amazon EC2 micro instance. There are about 7 million items in the db. I'm trying to iterate over all of them and print out some information about each item. I'm using the python wrapper to do so.

```
import pymongo as p
db_client = p.MongoClient()
db = db_client.my_awesome_db
photo_collection = db.photos
for photo in photo_collection.find():
    print photo['attr']
```

I'm not storing anything in memory and the DB isn't being used by anything else.

Since the query was running long, I used `limit()` to estimate how long it should take. I'm seeing non-linear times, the larger I make the limit. For example,

- limit -> time
- 1,000 -> 1 second
- 10,000 -> 10 seconds
- 100,000 -> 720 seconds (~ 12 minutes)
- 700,000 -> 9000 seconds

This isn't ridiculous, but it's larger than linear (the jump from 10k to 100k seems pretty bad). I can easily iterate over a 7 million line file in a second, but at this rate it will take 25 hours to iterate over the whole DB.

Do I have something configured wrong? Is `find()` not the correct function to use?

Comment: this is EBS right? You know the more you access the disk the slower it will tend to become, right?

Comment: No I did not. Do you have a link explaining this behavior?